# Django Rest Framework Serializer to filter specific child to be nested under parent

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

There is a 4 levels nested relation.
Country->State->District->road (that has all states in a country , all districts in a state and so on)
A user sends data in separated arrays like country:["A","B"] state:["C","F","D"] and same for district and road.
I want to have a json structure where only the user sent states are there and same for the other two levels also.

Ex -

```
[
   {
    "country":[{
       "name":"A",
       "states":[{
            "name":"C",
            "district":[{
                   "name":"D"//only the user sent districts
                   "road":[{"name":"saf"}]
                   }]
           }]
      },{
        "name":"B",
         ....
     }]
}]
```

How can i achieve this using serializers because serializers are giving me all the states irrespective of what user selected

```
Road (name,id)
District (road(many to many),name,id)
State (district (many to many),name,id)
Country(State(many to many),name,id)
//from user saved into Request (country, state, district,road, id, name) 

class RequestSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   country=countrySerializer(many=True)
   state=stateSerializer(many=True)
   district=districtSerializer(many=True)
   road=roadSerializer(many=True)
   class Meta:
       Model=Request
       fields=("country","state","district","road","id")
```

Comment: Can you share your models and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @BrianDestura added some code